# How to minify php html output without removing IE conditional comments?

Tags: php

I minify my HTML pages whit this PHP script:

```
function compress_html($html)
{
    preg_match_all('!(<(?:code|pre|script).*>[^<]+</(?:code|pre|script)>)!', $html, $pre);
    $html = preg_replace('!<(?:code|pre).*>[^<]+</(?:code|pre)>!', '#pre#', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('#<!–[^\[].+–>#', '', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t]+/', ' ', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/>[\s]+</', '><', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $html);

    if (!empty($pre[0])) {
        foreach ($pre[0] as $tag) {
        $html = preg_replace('!#pre#!', $tag, $html,1);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

ob_start('compress_html');
```

There is a way to remove just the "HTML comments"...and not the IE conditional comments?

Thanks.

Comment: So take out that line. Also take out this one: `$html = preg_replace('#<!–[^\[].+–>#', '', $html);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't handle multi-line HTML comments, only removing the first line. Also, the savings you get from this are negligible if you/your server is using gzip compression. ie:

```
Uncompressed, un-minified page: 2209 bytes
Compressed,   un-minified page:  959 bytes

Uncompressed, minified page:    1973 bytes
Compressed,   minified page:     914 bytes
```

Last two points:

1. Minifying your HTML makes it near-impossible to read, so good luck troubleshooting anything.
2. Larger pages generally have *better* compression ratios, particularly if the data is repetitive.