# PHP bufffer output minify, NOT textarea/pre

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, minify

I'm using the buffer sanitizer, as seen in a PHP manual comment, but having trouble with double newlines in textareas.

When pulling a string out from my database, containing double/triple/quadruple newlines, and putting it into a `textarea`, the newlines are reduced to only a single newline.

Therefore: Is it possible to have the function exclude all output between `<pre>`, `<textarea>` and `</pre>`, `</textarea>`?

Seeing this question, [How to minify php html output without removing IE conditional comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505881/how-to-minify-php-html-output-without-removing-ie-conditional-comments), I think i need to use the `preg_match`, but I'm not sure how to implement it into this function.

The function I'm using is

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

ob_start("sanitize_output");
```

And yeah I'm using both this sanitizer and `GZIP` to get the smallest size possible.

Comment: If You don't have time, there is a really stupid solution: preg_replace eveything between each textarea and each pre to a random_string (saving the original content in array(random_string = 'original content'); then run Your procedure, and then preg replace it back (random_string -> array('random_string');. You can implement it easily, and wait for a better answer. If You can wait, wait because this is a really ugly solution :).

Comment: Just a random thought (I didn't test it): write a function that given a string puts it into a list and returns an unique ID (the index in list f.e.). Use the function to "output" the strings you want to put in `<textarea>` elements. Let the minifier ob handler do its job then grab its output, identify the `textarea` elements and replace the IDs with the texts you saved before. Finding something like `<textarea>1</textarea>` is much easier than stripping the spaces; it can be done even without `regex` (but it's easier with them). Pack the list and the functions in a class and you're good to go.

Comment: @axiac Thats basically the approach of the first comment

Comment: Oops, I didn't read it before. Now I see it's very similar. Jacek's suggestion is to identify and extract the strings before running the function displayed in the question. Mine is to not put them in the output in the first place.

Comment: Can you not add additional search regex's for the textarea and pre tags like `'/(<textarea.*/textarea>)/'` and in the replace array add a `'\\1'`? or does that fail also?

Comment: Just a thought: I don't know why you want to to such sanitize jobs in HTML, but generally there is no special need of compressing the HTML with this technique. There is no really easy solution for your issue and maybe this will generate a big overhead that you do not really need. Maybe without the sanitize function your site is served faster. You should think about it and maybe test the benefit on your specific site.

Comment: @BrainFooLong, this will absolutely be tested when the final sanitizer is complete :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is an implementation of the function mentioned in the comments:

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {

    // Searching textarea and pre
    preg_match_all('#\<textarea.*\>.*\<\/textarea\>#Uis', $buffer, $foundTxt);
    preg_match_all('#\<pre.*\>.*\<\/pre\>#Uis', $buffer, $foundPre);

    // replacing both with <textarea>$index</textarea> / <pre>$index</pre>
    $buffer = str_replace($foundTxt[0], array_map(function($el){ return '<textarea>'.$el.'</textarea>'; }, array_keys($foundTxt[0])), $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace($foundPre[0], array_map(function($el){ return '<pre>'.$el.'</pre>'; }, array_keys($foundPre[0])), $buffer);

    // your stuff
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    // Replacing back with content
    $buffer = str_replace(array_map(function($el){ return '<textarea>'.$el.'</textarea>'; }, array_keys($foundTxt[0])), $foundTxt[0], $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array_map(function($el){ return '<pre>'.$el.'</pre>'; }, array_keys($foundPre[0])), $foundPre[0], $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}
```

There is always room for optimation but that works

Comment: Unfortunately replacing the original function with this the result is that absolutely nothing gets sanitized

Comment: @Behrens in my case it works as expected. All Html is sanitized except the content of `textarea` and `pre`. I left out the `ob_start(...)` at the end because that wasnt relevant but I cant imagine that you forgot about that. Just try this script alone with some output and see if you can make it work

Comment: Ah, You're absolutely right. I left out the ob_start. It works perfectly in <pre>, but not in <textarea>.. I think it's because of the attributes in the textareas? ex. <textarea name='' id='' class='' ... >

Comment: Yes - you are right. I completely forgot about that.Mh... I think updating the regex in `preg_match_all` to your needs will solve the issue since I replace back the old textarea-tag at the end anyway. So try `'#\<textarea.*\>(.*)\<\/textarea\>#Uis'`. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for `PRE` that does not work for `TEXTAREA`: replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` then use `nl2br()` to replace the newlines with `BR` elements before outputting the values. It's not elegant but it works:

```
<pre><?php
    echo(nl2br(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', htmlspecialchars($value))));
?></pre>
```

Unfortunately, it cannot be used for `TEXTAREA` because the browsers display `<br />` as text.

Comment: You can do that with a little more code:
`$textWithBr = nl2br(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', htmlspecialchars($value));`  

`$text = str_replace('<br />', '\n', $textWithBr);`

Comment: I want a universal function to do this, instead of doing it in every textarea. The <textarea> has first priority, the <pre> is only "nice-to-have"

Comment: @KalebKlein it's `"\n"` (with quotes, not apostrophes) but it doesn't help. It only undoes the effect of `nl2br`. If this could help for `TEXTAREA`s I wouldn't call `nl2br()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nl2ascii($str){
    return str_replace(array("\n","\r"), array("&#10;","&#13;"), $str);
}

$StrTest = "test\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\rtest";

ob_start("sanitize_output");
?>

<textarea><?php echo nl2ascii($StrTest); ?></textarea>
<textarea><?php echo $StrTest; ?></textarea>

<pre style="border: 1px solid red"><?php echo nl2ascii($StrTest); ?></pre>
<pre style="border: 1px solid red"><?php echo $StrTest; ?></pre>

<?php
ob_flush();
```

raw output

```
      <textarea>test&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;test</textarea>
<textarea>test
test</textarea>

<pre style="border: 1px solid red">test&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;test</pre>
<pre style="border: 1px solid red">test
test</pre>
```

visual output

[image]
[image]

Comment: This can be helpful (the best answer so far for me), however, getting the textarea and pre nodes is the most complicated part of this question. It mean, how to run Your replacement only on textarea and pre nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you the result you need.
But in general i do not recommend this kind of sanitize jobs, it's not good for performance. In these days there is no really need of stripping whitespace characters from a html output.

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
    $ignoreTags = array("textarea", "pre");

    # find tags that must be ignored and replace it with a placeholder
    $tmpReplacements = array();
    foreach($ignoreTags as $tag){
        preg_match_all("~<$tag.*?>.*?</$tag>~is", $buffer, $match);
        if($match && $match[0]){
            foreach($match[0] as $key => $value){
                if(!isset($tmpReplacements[$tag])) $tmpReplacements[$tag] = array();
                $index = count($tmpReplacements[$tag]);
                $replacementValue = "<tmp-replacement>$index</tmp-relacement>";
                $tmpReplacements[$tag][$index] = array($value, $replacementValue);
                $buffer = str_replace($value, $replacementValue, $buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    # re-insert previously ignored tags
    foreach($tmpReplacements as $tag => $rows){
        foreach($rows as $values){
            $buffer = str_replace($values[1], $values[0], $buffer);
        }
    }

    return $buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the sanitize HTML. I have commented the code, so it should be clear what it is doing.

```
function comprimeer($html = '', $arr_tags = ['textarea', 'pre']) {
    $arr_found = [];
    $arr_back = [];
    $arr_temp = [];

    // foreach tag get an array with tag and its content
    // the array is like: $arr_temp[0] = [ 0 = ['<tag>content</tag>'] ];
    foreach ($arr_tags as $tag) {
        if(preg_match_all('#\<' . $tag . '.*\>.*\<\/' . $tag . '\>#Uis', $html, $arr_temp)) {
            // the tag is present
            foreach($arr_temp as $key => $arr_item) {
                // for every item of the tag keep the item
                $arr_found[$tag][] = $arr_item[0];
                // make an nmubered replace <tag>1</tag>
                $arr_back[$tag][] = '<' . $tag . '>' . $key . '</' . $tag . '>';
            }
            // replace all the present tags with the numbered ones
            $html = str_replace((array) $arr_found[$tag], (array) $arr_back[$tag], $html);
        }
    } // end foreach

    // clean the html
    $arr_search = [
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s', // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s', // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'     // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    ];
    $arr_replace = [
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    ];
    $clean = preg_replace($arr_search, $arr_replace, $html);

    // put the kept items back
    foreach ($arr_tags as $tag) {
        if(isset($arr_found[$tag])) {
            // the tag was present replace them back
            $clean = str_replace($arr_back[$tag], $arr_found[$tag], $clean);
        }   
    } // end foreach
    // give the cleaned html back
    return $clean;
} // end function
```

Comment: Where is this answer to a 5 year old question, better than the one already accepted?